# FTPWebRequest EnableSsl = true returns (530) Not logged in

Tags: c#, .net, security, ftp, ftps

I want to download a file from the FTP server via SSL. If I don't enable enableSSL, the download works. If I activate enableSSL, I get the error message "(530) Not logged in". We have a vManaged Server. Does something on the server have to be changed for enableSSL to work or what am I doing wrong?

```
        FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("ftp://meineSeite/03-29-18_16-04-28_078.pdf");

        ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName: "hansMeier", password: "test1232121321");

        ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        ftpWebRequest.EnableSsl = true;

        Stream responseStream = ftpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Assembly\Desktop\FtpTest\test.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Download erfolgreich");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you login with TLS/SSL using any (GUI) FTP client? Show us its log file.

Answer (score 0):

try  `Normalize()` Method with your username and password like this

```
 ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
 usernameVariable.Normalize(),
 passwordVariable.Normalize(),
 domainVariable.Normalize()
);
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Why should this help? The credentials are pure ascii.

Comment: This might be useful to you !! 


https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f93be807-939e-4859-8815-f288e194d61d/ftp-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-530-not-logged-in?forum=csharpgeneral